# How to get SSO SAML working on a Liberty Java Application

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

Could anyone help talk me through how to implement SSO for an application on Bluemix please?

I have a liberty for java application that within the application there is an IBM Admin link within the tool that can be selected and used to have SSO working here, but the version had expired and the creator of this app has since left so I am having to maintain this app and now fix/upgrade the SSO connection for the Admin user. I have re-binded SSO (the newer version) to the app, using SAML. I have been boarded/registered and have completed the details/uploaded the metadata file. Now I really need some advice/help in what can be done to actually get this working so when the IBM Admin selects the link to login, it takes them to the admin version of the tool rather than an error where the SSO is not present currently.

If any details are needed please let me know and will provide.

Server.xmal details:-

```
enter code here<server>
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsf-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature>
    <feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>managedBeans-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
    <feature>icap:managementConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appstate-1.0</feature>
    <feature>cloudAutowiring-1.0</feature>
    <feature>openidConnectClient-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
</featureManager>
<application name='myapp' location='myapp.war' type='war' context-root='/'/>
<httpEndpoint id='defaultHttpEndpoint' host='*' httpPort='${port}'/>
<webContainer trustHostHeaderPort='true' extractHostHeaderPort='true'/>
<include location='runtime-vars.xml'/>
<logging logDirectory='${application.log.dir}' consoleLogLevel='INFO'/>
<httpDispatcher enableWelcomePage='false'/>
<applicationMonitor dropinsEnabled='false' updateTrigger='mbean'/>
<config updateTrigger='mbean'/>
<appstate appName='myapp' markerPath='${home}/../.liberty.state'/>
<dataSource id='mysql-ClearDB MySQL Database-assessments' jdbcDriverRef='mysql-driver' jndiName='jdbc/ClearDB MySQL Database-assessments' transactional='true' type='javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource'>
    <properties id='mysql-ClearDB MySQL Database-assessments-props' databaseName='${cloud.services.ClearDB MySQL Database-assessments.connection.name}' user='${cloud.services.ClearDB MySQL Database-assessments.connection.user}' password='${cloud.services.ClearDB MySQL Database-assessments.connection.password}' portNumber='${cloud.services.ClearDB MySQL Database-assessments.connection.port}' serverName='${cloud.services.ClearDB MySQL Database-assessments.connection.host}'/>
    <connectionManager id='mysql-ClearDB MySQL Database-assessments-conMgr' maxPoolSize='10'/>
</dataSource>
<jdbcDriver id='mysql-driver' javax.sql.XADataSource='org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource' javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource='org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource' libraryRef='mysql-library'/>
<library id='mysql-library'>
    <fileset id='mysql-fileset' dir='${server.config.dir}/lib'/>
</library>
<openidConnectClient id='${cloud.services.SSO-Assessments.connection.clientId}' clientId='${cloud.services.SSO-Assessments.connection.clientId}' clientSecret='${cloud.services.SSO-Assessments.connection.secret}' authorizationEndpointUrl='${cloud.services.SSO-Assessments.connection.authorizationEndpointUrl}' tokenEndpointUrl='${cloud.services.SSO-Assessments.connection.tokenEndpointUrl}' redirectToRPHostAndPort='https://AssessmentsSolution-Network.mybluemix.net:443' issuerIdentifier='${cloud.services.SSO-Assessments.connection.issuerIdentifier}' scope='${cloud.services.SSO-Assessments.connection.serverSupportedScope}' httpsRequired='true'/>
<keyStore id='defaultKeyStore' password='changeit' type='jks' location='${java.home}/lib/security/cacerts'/>
```

Comment: Do you know what features are currently being used?

Comment: @Alasdair Hi, sorry - features being used by what? SSO or my bluemix application?

Comment: The bluemix application. It should be visible in the file view for your deployed application instance visible in the bluemix console.

Comment: @Alasdair Sorry for delayed response, have been on vacation. I have a list of features within the server.xml file within files and logs on the Bluemix app - is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.

Comment: @Alasdair Please see above for contents of server.xml